# Trying to spy on a function using sinon but got an error

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have file called email it has a method called sendemail which call create message

```
//email.js
const createEmail = function (to, from, subject, bodyText) {
   const emailLines = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
     "to: ", to, "\n",
     "from: ", from, "\n",
     "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
     bodyText
   ].join('');
   return emailLines
 }


   const sendemail = function(to, from, subject, bodyText){
     const message = createemail(to, from, message);
     auth = getauth();
     sendmessagetogoogleapi(auth, message)
}
 module.exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
 module.exports.createEmail = createEmail;
```

and the test file is like the bellow

```
describe('Send email should call the createmessage method', function(){
    it('it should call the method ',function(){
      const createEmail = sinon.stub('createEmail');
      sendEmail('otest@domain.de',test2@domain','test','this is test',['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])
      expect(createEmail.called).to.be.true;
      done();

    })
})
```

I got this error

> ```
>  TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
> ```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You don't use `const createEmail` anywhere, so it obviously isn't called. You have `createemail` and `createEmail` in email.js, is it a typo?. You can't spy on `createEmail` from email.js. You could do that if it was located in different module or was used as a method, `exports.createEmail(...)`.

Comment: Do you mean I have to separate createEmail and sendEmail in a different module?

Comment: Yes, this is needed if you need to be able to test them separately. Otherwise you will have to test them as a single unit.

Comment: I did that, and I console.log in createEmail and it printed on screen
but the       expect(createEmails.called).to.be.true;
 is false

Comment: Please, update the question with your attempt. If you did that with multiple modules, this should involve module mocking.

Answer (score 0):

In your test/spec file, you need to import email.js.

```
let email = require('email.js')
let createEmailStub = sinon.stub(email, "createEmail")
email.sendEmail('otest@domain.de',test2@domain','test','this is test',['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])
expect(createEmailStub.called).to.be.true;
sinon.assert.calledOnce(creatEmailStub);
createEmailStub.restore(); // you need to restore stub after use. Or you can put it in afterEach function.
done();
```